# What is a good pre-G rank armor/weapon set for hunting Alatreon in MH3U?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

In Monster Hunter Tri Ultimate's offline mode, one of the last missions you get is hunting the Alatreon at high-rank (I believe). Thing is, I'm used to hunting it on the older Wii version with the assistance of three other hunters using sleepbombing, and have never tried soloing it before. What would be a good High rank/early G-rank armor set or element/ailment weapon type to use for hunting the Alatreon with the aid of only your Shakalaka companions?

Comment: Which weapons do you use? Because any weapon type will work, it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Long Sword, mostly. Sometimes will go SnS or DS, but not too often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mostly depends on your weapon and fighting style.

If you use any low-mobility weapons such as a Greatsword, either Quick Sheathing is always a good idea so you can switch to running as soon as possible. Alatreon does move fairly often and fairly quickly so you want to stay with him as much as possible so you can deal as much damage as possible to her. There are very few suggestions that don't depend on how you play.

Alatreon deals pretty much every elemental damage, so don't bother blindly gearing for elemental resistance. Instead, if you're going to focus on resisting damage, focus on what weapon you are going to be using. If you are a Blademaster, you most likely want to gear for general Defense and Fire Resist, keeping Thunder Resist in mind as well. Gunners will likely want to have strong resistances toward Ice and Dragon as all of Alatreon's Ice attacks are ranged and his Dragon charge is surprisingly quick. Gunners will also want to have at least 0 Resist to Fire (no weakness) if you're bad at dodging fireballs because Alatreon does spew those with minor frequency.

Rather than going for a specific armor set, do some research on Alatreon. Watch videos and learn her tells. Like most monsters, the strongest weapon you can bring to any monster fight is knowledge.

Comment: I remember most of its tells and moves from the Wii version, I was mostly just asking about armor with a good set of resistances that won't get me one-shotted despite high Defense. Good advice about not worrying too much about that, though I'm still wondering what element would be best for solo. If it helps, I was planning to go Longsword on it.